# How do I include basic formatting in C# Bad Request error message string?

Tags: c#, reactjs

I am trying to construct an error string that lists a certain number of items that will be affected.  I want it to look something like this.

```
You are unable to delete this because it will affect the following stuff:

stuff1
stuff2
stuff3

Please remove the stuff before deleting.
```

I'm trying something like:

```
string errorMessage =
    "You are unable to delete this because it will affect the following stuff:" + 
    "<br> stuff1" +
    "<br> stuff2" +
    "<br> stuff3" +
    "<br>" +
    "Please remove the stuff before deleting."; 

...
return BadRequest(errorMessage);
```

The reason I am doing this is because on my front-end, I am using React to take these error messages and display an error message modal.  But it just shows the tags directly in the error message now.  I can't figure out how to easily bold or italicize parts of the text either.  Is it possible to send a BadRequest with formatted text for the front-end to take and display?

Comment: Please show the calling code, and the server you are using (MVC, Web API, ASP.NET Core)

Comment: You can use `jQuery.parseHTML()` on your front end. Haven't used React before so I apologize in advance if JQuery is incompatible, but that's what I'd normally do.

Comment: just my 2 cents, you shouldn't do any formatting like that. Instead return the errors, even custom error object and let the front end do the formatting

Comment: @AD.Net wouldn't that require manipulating the string to insert delimiters for the front end to parse anyway?

Comment: @BrandonMiller, an error object can be sent from server and you can have templates to show the error in any way you like, with the usual binding. Otherwise you're creating a tight coupling with the UI and backend, and likely breaking some best practices

Comment: I would defer to what others have said, but if all else fails, you can use [reacts dangerouslySetInnerHTML](https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#dangerouslysetinnerhtml).

Answer (score -1):

A little bit too wide answer but still:

Use Markdown (MD) formatted text for error messages and display them in React MD renderer.
Why MD? Error messages should be logged and in logs MD text looks much better then HTML. Together you will solve this your problem.